# Testing in app purchases with remote console impossible?

Tags: android, cordova

So the requirements for in-app purchases testing is that the **app is signed**.

And the requirements for chrome inspector to work is that the **app must not be signed**.

Is it possible to debug in app purchases with chrome inspector?